# Estrutura para projeto em PHP e utilização da função eval()

Tags: php, otimização, eval

Preciso desenvolver uma aplicação que se adeque a vários projetos com funcionalidades em comum, entretanto cada um possui várias regras específicas.

O que eu preciso é uma estrutura que me permita fácil alteração dessas regras, no caso escolhi salvar as regras no banco de dados e utilizar a função `eval()` para executar o código na aplicação, contudo, eu não acho que essa seria a melhor opção para chegar ao resultado que preciso (nem a mais segura, mesmo que as regras estejam criptografadas).

Estrutura estou utilizando agora é:

```
app
    controller [controllers]
    model [models] [aqui são aplicados as regras do banco de dados]
    entity [entidades do banco de dados]
    repository [model <=> entity]
    helper [helpers]
    view [views]
    theme [themes]
config
    [configurações da aplicação]
data
    logs [app logs]
    cache [view cache]
public 
    [módulos angular, assets, index.php e .htaccess]
vendor
    [libraries, app-core]
```

As regras seriam aplicadas mais ou menos assim:

```
// Random key (config)
define('PRIVATE_KEY', 'SECURE_RANDOM_KEY');

// antes

foreach ( regras as regra )
    parse(decode(regra, PRIVATE_KEY));

// continua execução
```

Alguma ideia de como eu poderia melhorar isso?

Comment: Corre de `eval` ou `preg_replace` com modificador `e`. Não é uma boa idéia mesmo

Comment: a estrutura está bacana. Apenas aconselho a incluir uma pasta "lib" ou "libraries" dentro da pasta "app". Você tem "libraries" para "vendor", porém, precisa ter suas libraries para a engine do app. Outro que acho importante é "override". Dentro dessa pasta teria a mesma estrutura dos folders "app" e "config". Override é para poder permitir que o programador customize funções nativas sem precisar modificar os arquivos originais. A grosso modo, override, é uma "gambiarra organizada".

Answer (score 1):

Porque você não utiliza classes? Por exemplo:

```
interface Regras {
    public function execute();
}

class RegrasApp implements Regras {
    public function execute() {
        // suas regras aqui
    }
}

$regras = new RegrasApp();
$regras->execute();
```

Comment: Onde ficariam essas classes? Essa estrutura deve ser capaz de suportar vários projetos (10+), como que eu poderia gerenciar as regras de cada projeto?

Comment: Onde as classes ficam? Onde você achar mais adequado.. Cada projeto teria sua própria classe contendo as regras de negócio que seriam executadas pelo método `execute` sendo que você apenas precisa instanciar o objeto correto.

Comment: Será que seria interessante eu usar classes invocáveis __invoke() e chamar as regras uma por uma utilizando um SplStack?

Comment: Não aconselho a utilizar o `__invoke`. É muito mais simples para alguém que não conhece seu código entender como o mesmo funciona a partir da chamada de um método.

Comment: A pessoa usaria algo assim: $filter->register('filtros.produto', function(){  }); como callback.